# Query from two tables laravel with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to write this query in Laravel query

```sql
SELECT
    table1.*, table2.* 
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    table2
ON
    (table1.id = table2.id AND (table2.field =  '' OR table2.field >=  '0'))
WHERE
    table.id = id
```

I have problem with how to add inner part `AND ( ... )` to the query? Here is what I have so far

```php
$query = Table::select(
    DB::Raw('table1.*, table2.*'))
        ->leftJoin('table2', function($join) {
            $join->on('table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')
                 ->where('table2.field', '=', '')
                 ->orwhere('table2.field', '=', '50');
})->where('table1.id', BaseController::getCurrentUser()->id)
  ->get();
```

I miss where and how to add `AND` ...

Comment: Small correction there is a semicolen after this statement like: $query->where('table2.field', '') ->orWhere('table2.field', 50);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to have the `AND` part as part of `ON`? If you move it to the `WHERE` part of your query you could use something like:

```php
$query = Table::select('table1.*', 'table2.*') 
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')   
    ->where('table1.id', BaseController::getCurrentUser()->id)
    ->where(function ($query){
        $query->where('table2.field', '')
              ->orWhere('table2.field', 50)
});
```

The result should be the same as from your original query.